# aligning image with center of page css

Tags: html, css, reactjs

I have this code for my image:

```
return <div class="imgContainer"><img src={broomAndText} alt="broomAndText" /></div>
```

in my css file, I have this:

```
 .imgContainer {
    text-align: center;    
}
```

but on mobile, and on desktop, it goes to the right side of the page, instead of actually centering it. How do i fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```css
.imgContainer{
display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    height: 100vh;
}
```

```html
<div class="imgContainer"><img src="https://www.w3schools.com/tags/img_girl.jpg" alt="Girl in a jacket" width="300" height="300">
</div>
```

You can see here, RUN this SNippet

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
.imgContainer {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}
```

Comment: thanks for the reply, this worked on desktop, but not mobile :(

Comment: Could it be because the image doesn't resize properly on mobile or something else changes its style on different screen sizes?

Comment: that is the only place I am setting the css for the div, so it shouldn't. It is a gif, not sure if that would make a difference, but i would assume it should size down as the screen gets smaller as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this also by using the position

```
.imgContainer{

    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

With using display: flex, you can make image center vertically and horizontally

```
.imgContainer{
display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    height: 100vh;
}
```

Comment: I like this approach! However, it made it work on the desktop, but not the mobile. When I use the device toolbar in the browser, and size it down, it doesn't adjust with the size of the page, but moves all the way to the right .

Answer (score 0):

In your html head tag add this

CSS

```
.imgContainer{
display:flex;
width: 100vw:
justify-content: center;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
<div class="main_container">
  <div class="container">
    <img src="img1.jpg" />
  </div>
</div>
```

```
display: flex;
align-items: center;
justify-content: center;
```

}

Comment: Add some explanation to your answer